# How to extract the key values from a function within a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have data about the movies in the format of the dictionary, like the example below:

```
 {'Similar': {'Info': [{'Name': 'Tony Bennett', 'Type': 'music'}], 'Results': [{'Name': 'The Startup Kids', 'Type': 'movie'}, {'Name': 'Charlie Chaplin', 'Type': 'movie'}, {'Name': 'Venus In Fur', 'Type': 'movie'}, {'Name': 'Loving', 'Type': 'movie'}, {'Name': 'The African Queen', 'Type': 'movie'}]}}
```

I need to extract movie names from that, but I am getting different errors on the go. Have been trying many things, but haven't found a solution.

I created the function get_movies_from_tastedive(movies), to have my data on movies from TasteDive (Part 1) and then I defined a second function, (Part 2) extract_movie_titles for getting the movie titles.

Getting a KeyError: KeyError: Similar on line 23 
- I am running it in runestone learning environment and it also shows: {'error': 'Response not interpretable as json. Try printing the .text attribute'}. 
- If I try to print .text it says that AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'text' on line 21

## Part 1

```
def get_movies_from_tastedive(movies):
    baseurl = "https://tastedive.com/api/similar"
    params_diction = {}
    params_diction["q"] = movies
    params_diction["type"] = "movies"
    params_diction["limit"] = 5 
    movie_resp = requests_with_caching.get(baseurl, params = params_diction)
    #print(movie_resp.json())
    return movie_resp.json()
```

## Part 2

```
def extract_movie_titles(movies):
    t = get_movies_from_tastedive(movies) 
    #title = t.text
    #print(title)
    return [d['Name'] for d in t['Similar']['Info']]


extract_movie_titles(get_movies_from_tastedive("Tony Bennett"))
extract_movie_titles(get_movies_from_tastedive("Bridesmaids"))
```

The expected result should be: ['The Startup Kids', 'Charlie Chaplin’], ‘Venus In Fur’, ‘Loving’, ‘The African Queen’] but getting a KeyError: Similar on line 23

Answer (score 2):

The info you are looking for is in t['Similar']['Results']

Following code worked for me :

```
d =  {'Similar': {'Info': [{'Name': 'Tony Bennett', 'Type': 'music'}], 'Results': [{'Name': 'The Startup Kids', 'Type': 'movie'}, {'Name': 'Charlie Chaplin', 'Type': 'movie'}, {'Name': 'Venus In Fur', 'Type': 'movie'}, {'Name': 'Loving', 'Type': 'movie'}, {'Name': 'The African Queen', 'Type': 'movie'}]}}


def extract_movie_titles(d):
   return [m['Name'] for m in d['Similar']['Results']]

print (extract_movie_titles(d))
```

Output: 
[image]